# My website show this weird blank space in the right after I placed this div which shouldn't do it

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my webpage.
http://ownscene.com/index-en.html

The problem is with the embed video in 2nd section.

Here is the code

```html
  <!-- present -->
<section class="no-padding bg-primary">    
<div>
  <div class="row">
    <div style="color: #fff;" class="col-lg-2"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 wow fadeIn" >
 
                        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/HLKPZ-vFYqI"></iframe>
                        </div>

        </div>  
    <div style="color: #fff;" class="col-lg-2"></div>
</div>
</section>
<!-- present -->
```

I tried removing both left and right div and weird blank space is gone.
I don't know what to do, I want it to be centered and smaller on lg then take full space in md

Please help

Thank you,

Comment: are you referring to the thin strip that runs all across the screen on the right due to which you have a horizontal scroll?

Comment: A screenshot with a circle around exactly what the problem is would help.  The link to your page is just... a really long intro with multiple videos and multiple icons.  I have no idea what kind of "weird blank space" to look for.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `col-lg-offset`

```
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-0 wow fadeIn" >
         <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
             <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/HLKPZ-vFYqI"></iframe>
         </div>
     </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: wow this one fixed it for me perfectly, thank you.

Now I have to learn more about this offset command.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the border using CSS since iframe has default border

```
<iframe style="border: 0 none" class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/HLKPZ-vFYqI"></iframe>
```